# Pandas DataFrame to lists of lists including headers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], 
                   [4, 5, 6], 
                   [7, 8, 9]], 
                   columns=['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'])
>>> df
   Col 1  Col 2  Col 3
0      1      2      3
1      4      5      6
2      7      8      9
```

Is there a Pandas way of returning the DataFrame as a list of lists with the headers included?

I can return the headers and values as lists as follows

```
>>> df.columns.values.tolist()
['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3']
>>> df.values.tolist()
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> df.tolist()
```

But how could I return the following result?

```
[['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use double transpose with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.T.reset_index().values.T.tolist())
[['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Or nicer [insert](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
a = df.columns.values.tolist()
b = df.values.tolist()

b.insert(0, a)
print (b)
[['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Nice, both suggestions work better than my original implementation. For my first attempt I used `numpy.row_stack()` in a similar implementation to that which you used for `insert`

Answer (score 5):

You have two lists, so using:

```
[df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
>>> [['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```